# Foreach no Laravel só retorna a primeira linha

Tags: php, json, laravel, foreach, controller

Tenho o Seguindo código abaixo no Laravel 7

A minha controller está está pegando o relacionamento de muitos para um conforme o Model abaixo:

```
public function listarPermissoes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Acoes::class, 'id_permissao','id');
    }
```

No meu controller está da seguinte forma:

```
public function index()
    {
        $permissoes = Permissoes::all();

        foreach($permissoes as $permissao)
        {
            $permissao->listarPermissoes;
            return $permissao;
        }

    }
```

O retorno do código está me retornando apenas a primeira permissão, sendo que tenho várias permissões no banco de dados. 
Abaixo segue o exemplo de como está vindo:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "Módulo Gerencia de Alunos",
    "list_permissions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "Ver dados"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": "Listar dados"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "value": "Excluir dados"
        }
    ]
}
```

O resultado que busco e trazer o seguinte json abaixo:

```
{
  "id": 1,
    "value": "Módulo Gerencia de Alunos",
    "list_permissions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "Ver dados"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": "Listar dados"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "value": "Excluir dados"
        }
    ]

},
{
"id": 2,
    "value": "Módulo Gerencia de Turmas",
    "list_permissions": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "value": "Ver dados"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "value": "Listar dados"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "value": "Excluir dados"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Retira o return... usa um echo ou procure uma outra forma de exibir.
O return cancela o código depois da primeira execução.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está fazendo colocando o `return` dentro do loop, o mesmo está saindo assim que ele executa o primeiro passo. 
Se você deseja exibir para o usuário todos os itens, sugiro você escrever utilizando o `print_r()`.